# tac command's option creates strange output [comprehension question]

Tags: text-processing, utilities, coreutils

Say I have this file, containing nothing but

```
a
b
c
b
a
```

Using `tac --separator=a file` in BASH [on a Debian based Linux], I get this:

```
                  # empty line
                  # empty line
b
c
b
aacommand@prompt  # two a just before the prompt
```

**Question**: As far as I understood, `--separator=a` defines that `a` marks the break inside the string, instead of `newline`. **Is this right?**

I have tried this with other strings an much more input and ended up with quite a mess. The other options all work quite right, I presume: If I use `tac --before` I first get about five than one empty lines, but then this is about what should happen, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tac` is easier to understand in the case it's primarily designed for, which is when the separator is a record terminator, i.e. the separator appears after the last record. It prints the records (including each terminator) in reverse order.

```
$ echo -n fooabara | tac -s a; echo
rabafooa
```

The input consists of three records (`foo`, `b` and `r`), each followed by the separator `a`; the output consists of three records (`r`, `b` and `foo`), each followed by the separator `a`.

If the last record doesn't end with a record terminator, it's still printed first, with no record separator.

```
$ echo -n fooabar | tac -s a; echo
rbafooa
```

The last record `r` ends up concatenated with the next-to-last record `b` with no separator in between, since there was no separator at the end of the last record.

Your input looks a bit more confusing because of the newlines. Let's see it with commas instead of newlines:

```
$ echo -n a,b,c,b,a, | tac -s a; echo
,,b,c,b,aa
```

There are three input records: an empty one (with a terminator `a`), the bulky one `,,b,c,b,` (again with a terminator), and an unterminated `,` at the end. These records (each with their terminator, except for the last record which doesn't have a terminator) are printed in reverse order.

Your confusion probably comes from expecting the “separator” to be a separator — but that's a misnomer: it's really a record terminator. `--before` makes it an initiator instead.

Comment: Incredible answer, @Gilles, thank you very much! I really wonder where you get your information from, as I spent quite some time looking and found nothing close to what you provide here. Thank you so very much for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

The following example might help to use the `--regex` option:

```
$ cat records 
---1---
1
2
3
---2
A
B
C
---3--
a
b
c
$ tac --before --regex --separator=^---[0-9]+-*$ records
---3--
a
b
c
---2
A
B
C
---1---
1
2
3
```

In this example the file `records` contains multiline records, each started with a line (`^...$`) that starts with `---`, followed by a number (`[0-9]+`) and an optional sequence of minus signs (`-*`). One can see the order of lines in each record and its header line are preserved.

I use `tac` this way to show log files entries in reverse order, as used in feed applications such as twitter. For instance to print only the last two records in reversed order:

```
tac --before --regex --separator=^---[0-9]+-*$ example \
 | awk '/^---[0-9]+-*$/ {c++} c>2 {exit}{print}'
```